# Count objects using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have url `api/v1/posts/`. If we use GET request from that url, we can see all objects. For example:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/posts/11/",
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Sample name",
            "type": "Shirt",
            "collection": "Winter 2020"
        }
    ]
}
```

We need to create functional -

We can create GET request with filter. In our case, we need to filter "type": "Shirt" and we can see "Collection" with count (count shirts from all collections)

For example:

```
{
  "collection" : "Winter 2020"
  "result" : [
    {
     "count": 12
    }
  ]
}
```

Etc... How to create it using Django Rest Framework?

UPD (Added view):

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = ('name', 'type')


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: can you share your view for api/v1/posts/ url pls?

Comment: @engin_ipek I did update

Comment: so can you filter your results but cannot return a customized result?

Comment: @engin_ipek yes. I don't know how to customize filter result.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your Posts by collection and return the count of each collection.

Add this method to your viewset: ( You need to import `from django.db.models import Count` too.)

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        result_list = list(queryset.values('collection').annotate(count=Count('collection')))
        return Response(result_list)
```